# Why the usage of ++ is different in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a class `Deduction` which has a property `Sequence` of `int` type:

```
public class Deduction
{
   private int _sequence;
   public int Sequence
   {
      get { return _sequence; }
      set { _sequence = value; }
   } 
   ...
}
```

Now I have an object of `Deduction` type and its `Sequence` property has the value of 1:

```
Deduction deduction = new Deduction();
deduction.Sequence = 1;
```

Now I have a variable `newSequence` of `int` type whose value is -1:

```
int newSequence = -1;
```

I want to take the current value of `Sequence` property of `deduction` object, add 1 and store the result in `newSequence` variable. So I wrote this code:

```
newSequence = deduction.Sequence++;
```

But what I find out is that the above code changes the value of `Sequence` property of `deduction` object to **2** from **1** while I was expecting it will remain at **1**.

And also the above code changes the value of `newSequence` to **1** from **-1** while I was expecting it will change to `2`.

This is weird. Can somebody explain what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx)?

Comment: @AlexM. You should explain what's not good about it.

Comment: You can read `variable++` as: 'first give me the value of variable, then increment variable', while `++variable` can be read as: 'increment variable, then give me its (already incremented) value'.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet That is incorrect.  The variable is always incremented, and then a value is returned.  What changes is whether it returns the original value or the incremented value.  This matters when considering statements with multiple side effects.

Comment: in what way is this behavior different from c++?

Comment: @pm100 The provided code is no different, but C++, unlike C#, does not rigidly define when the side effect happens, so statements accessing the same variable multiple times within that statement, that use this operator, can potentially behave differently.  Of course, this doesn't really happen in sane programs.

Comment: @Servy: You're correct, I'm just trying to explain how to interpret the prefix versus the postfix version in laymans terms.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet And doing so incorrectly is only going to lead to further confusion, or worse.

Comment: @Servy I don't see where in `newSequence = deduction.Sequence++;` there is multiple access to same variable. So even if in C++ sequence points can lead to uncertainty in evaluation order ; that isn't the case here

Comment: @mason guilty as charged; did not read the documentation

Comment: @Sehnsucht I specifically said it would be no different for the example given, but that for other situations not shown, it can differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
newSequence = deduction.Sequence++;
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
newSequence = deduction.Sequence;
deduction.Sequence = deduction.Sequence + 1;
```

Make more sense now?

If you did this:

```
newSequence = ++deduction.Sequence;
```

It turns into this:

```
deduction.Sequence = deduction.Sequence + 1;
newSequence = deduction.Sequence;
```

As others have said, you are probably not looking to change `deduction.Sequence`, so you want to use this:

```
newSequence = deduction.Sequence + 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

`++` increments the value it is next to.  If you have the operator (`++`) *after* the variable/property, the variable increments by 1 *after* assignment.  If you have the `++` *before* the assignment, the variable increases prior to assignment.

It seems that what you are looking for is `newSequence = deduction.Sequence + 1;`

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx):

> The increment operator (++) increments its operand by 1. The increment
>   operator can appear before or after its operand: ++variable and
>   variable++. Remarks The first form is a prefix increment operation.
>   The result of the operation is the value of the operand after it has
>   been incremented. The second form is a postfix increment operation.
>   The result of the operation is the value of the operand before it has
>   been incremented. Numeric and enumeration types have predefined
>   increment operators. User-defined types can overload the ++ operator.
>   Operations on integral types are generally allowed on enumeration.

You may be missing the subtlety on how this works. By putting the operand on the end, the assignment is done then the increment.

Answer (score 1):

`++` is the **post** increment operator when it comes after the variable, which means that the increment happens after the assignment.

```
newSequence = deduction.Sequence++;
```

You're assigning the old value of `deduction.Sequence` to `newSequence`, *then* incrementing the value of `deduction.Sequence`.